# $\int_0^1\frac{f^2(t)}{t(1-t)}dt \leq \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 f'(t)^2 dt$

Tags: integration, inequality

> Let $f\in C^1([0,1],\mathbb R)$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$
>
> Prove that $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{f^2(t)}{t(1-t)}dt \leq \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 f'(t)^2 dt$

First thing that bothers me is that the LHS is an improper integral.

Note that $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f'(t)dt =0$.

I tried integration by parts, but I  can't get the RHS.

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{f(t)}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t-0} = f'(0) $ this number exists since $f \in C^1([0,1])$.

Comment: @johnmangual I should have seen that, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more like a comment than an answer but we have:

$$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{2} f'(t)^2 - \frac{f^2(t)}{t(1-t)}\right) dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \left(f'(t) - \frac{1-2t}{t(1-t)}f(t) \right)^2\,dt \ge 0$$

*Q.E.D.*

Comment: Very nice! Can you give a hint on how you came up with that idea?